# Why do I keep getting error 1004 Range of worksheet failed?

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to auto-refresh an advanced filter in Sheet2 using data and criteria from Sheet1. Seems straight forward enough but the following code results in a 1004 error with the range object no matter what I try. What am I missing?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("Sheet1!A1:C4").AdvancedFilter Action:=xIFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("Sheet1!E1:E2"), _
        CopyToRange:=Range("Sheet2!A1:B4"), _
        Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you change your `Range("Sheet1!A1:C4")` to `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C4")` and the same for the others as well.  That may do the trick.  I've just never referenced ranges in the manner you are in VBA, I always do the sheet then the range of the sheet.

Comment: Resulted in "AdvancedFilter method failed of Range object. Not sure if that's better or worse. :/

Comment: This `xIFilterCopy` looks suspicious.  I think the second character is an `i` and it should be an `l` as in `xlFilterCopy`

Comment: Damn! That was it. Works now. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implicit `Me.` in front of the `Range` call when it's called within a worksheet module.  So it's only looking in sheet2 for a range called "Sheet1!E1:E2".  It would work in a stand alone module (so you could create a procedure call) or if you use @Joshua Ross suggestion in the comments.